# Hadoop Job throws java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a simple map-reduce job. This job uses 250 files from common crawl data.

e.g. s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/

If I use, 50, 100 files, everything works OK. But with 250 files I get this error

```
java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
    at org.jets3t.service.io.InterruptableInputStream.read(InterruptableInputStream.java:76)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.read(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:111)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.readBuffer(SequenceFile.java:1707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.seekToCurrentValue(SequenceFile.java:1773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getCurrentValue(SequenceFile.java:1849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper$SubMapRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MultithreadedMapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper$MapRunner.run(MultithreadedMapper.java:268)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

How many map slots do you have to process the input? Is it close to 100?

This is a guess, but its possible that the connection to S3 is timing out whilst you process the first batch of files and as slots become available to process further files the connection is no longer open. I believe timeout errors from NativeS3FileSystem show up as IOExceptions.

Comment: Thanks! But what's the parameter name? Because I didn't find in here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html

Comment: Hi @BinaryNerd! Please take a little more time when reviewing suggested edits. You recently approved one that [made no change](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12378619).